# How do fiber bundles help us to solve problems on a manifold?

Tags: mathematical-physics, vector-bundles

I'm trying to generate some intuition as to how the tangent bundle and cotangent bundle work in the context of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian dynamics.

Discussions on this topic that I've found so far in other fora (like physics.se and quora) seem to focus on "what it enables us to do" which I appreciate, but I'm looking for a more mathematical explanation about how they encode information about the manifold, i.e. "how it lets us do those things."

Here is what I think I know. Please assume the context of a finite dimensional smooth real manifold like you would use in mechanics.

1. A smooth curve in the manifold tells you the position an instantaneous velocity at each point, and seemingly tells you everything about the situation already. Lagrangian and Hamiltonian dynamics move the problem to a curve in the tangent/cotangent bundles where ostensibly it is easier to find the right curve. So the tangent/cotangent bundles "enrich" the manifold to aid solving the problem.
2. At first it looked like the cotangent space was a refinement of an enrichment, but I've been getting a different impression now that they are simply *different* enrichments.  They have different qualities, and some of their functionals are paired naturally with the Legendre transformation.

Perhaps a categorical explanation would help me? To that end, I've looked at quite a few nLab articles, especially [this one](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+bundles+in+physics) and [this nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tangent+bundle+category#:%7E:text=A%20tangent%20bundle%20category%20is,given%20category%E2%80%9D%20constructed%20by%20abelianization.) but that latter one is pretty advanced for me at the moment.

I didn't write out the details but it seems to me like there is a covariant functor from the category of differentiable manifolds into itself that takes a manifold to its tangent bundle and each morphism to its pushforward, and likewise a contravariant functor for cotangent bundles that uses the pullback, and I'm hoping the second link essentially confirms that.

So, given that background

> How does passing to the tangent/cotangent bundles give us leverage as compared the original manifold?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of physics the point is that Newton's laws tell you that you need to know the initial position and momentum of a particle to predict its trajectory (let me stick to the cotangent bundle and Hamiltonian mechanics because I know how to say the thing I want to say for that case only). This is physical input; *a priori* physics could've turned out to work a different way, as far as I know.

So in other words, if you want to think of time evolution as a flow generated by a vector field on something, it's not a flow or a vector field on space $X$, because position is not enough information to determine time evolution. It *is* a flow / vector field on the cotangent bundle $T^{\ast}(X)$, because (position, momentum) *is* enough information to determine time evolution. And in fact time evolution is precisely the flow generated by the [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) associated to the Hamiltonian.

Zooming out a little, Hamiltonian mechanics has to somehow take as input a smooth function $H$ (the Hamiltonian) and produce as output a vector field $X_H$ (time evolution); moreover $X_H$ must have the property that $L_{X_H} H = 0$ (conservation of energy). And if you sit down and write out what properties this implies about the pairing $\{ f, g \} = L_{X_f} g$ on smooth functions you'll write down the axioms of a [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket). Now $T^{\ast}(X)$ is canonically a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold), so $C^{\infty}(T^{\ast}(X))$ canonically acquires a Poisson bracket defined by the symplectic form, and it turns out that Hamiltonian mechanics can be described entirely in terms of this bracket.

It is sometimes helpful to understand all of this as a classical limit of quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics the Poisson bracket becomes a commutator bracket on a noncommutative algebra of observables, time evolution is given on observables by exponentiating a commutator which corresponds to an inner automorphism

$$A \mapsto e^{\frac{i H t}{\hbar}} A e^{- \frac{i H t}{\hbar}}$$

(this is the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture)), and [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) reduces to the triviality that if $A$ and $H$ commute then $A$ is constant with respect to the above time evolution. From this point of view the significance of the cotangent bundle $T^{\ast}(X)$ is that it arises as the classical limit, suitably understood, of the noncommutative algebra of differential operators on $X$, and its Poisson bracket is a "commutative shadow" of this noncommutative origin. There are various versions of this story explaining how Poisson brackets show up as classical limits of commutator brackets, e.g. [deformation quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization).

Comment: OK, the first two paragraphs help a bit... any advice on how to understand why, when seeking a solution $q(t)$, it is somehow easier to find $(q(t), p(t))$?  Doubling the dimension of the manifold seems like it makes things more complex, but then again, you're somehow spreading out $n$ dimensions of information more thinly in the $2n$ dimensions, so I guess that is part of it?

Comment: @rschwieb: like I said, this is physical input coming from Newton's laws. You seem to be trying to see it as a purely mathematical phenomenon and I'm not aware of a way to do that (although maybe the classical limit story offers a hint of how it might be done). *A priori* Newton's laws could've told us that position was sufficient to determine time evolution, or that we need position and velocity and acceleration, and as it happens it told us neither of those.

Comment: I get where you're coming from that to determine the time evolution of a physical system requires position and one of momentum or velocity, and in that sense one of the bundles is a natural place to work since it acknowledges both inputs on equal footing. What I'm trying to get at (I think) is that high school mechanics seems to seek curves in $X$, and Lagrangian mechanics seeks curves in the tangent bundle, and Hamiltonian mechanics seeks curves in the cotangent bundle. The justification usually given is that 'the problem becomes easier to solve there." Do you have insight as to why?

Comment: Perhaps it is just something elementary that people who do a lot of differential equations understand. Somehow, taking the problem and separating it out into more coordinates allows you to find a solution more easily.

Comment: I don't follow what "it" is in "You seem to be trying to see it as a purely mathematical phenomenon". As far as I know I'm only talking about something mathematical yes: solutions to differential equations, I suppose.  Is the "physical, non-mathematical" contribution that you're talking about just the link between momentum and velocity?  Don't get me wrong, I appreciate this angle you've opened up.

Comment: @rschwieb: “it” refers to working with the tangent or cotangent bundle. Newton’s laws tell you that the position of a particle satisfies a second-order differential equation, so the initial conditions you need to specify are position and velocity. That’s physical input about the kinds of differential equations classical mechanics asks you to solve, not a fully general statement about all kinds of differential equations you might ever want to solve. It’s not a purely mathematical phenomenon (again, as far as I know).